# How can I take the .graphql files in my src folder and bundle them up to one schema.graphql file to my build folder

Tags: typescript, compilation, schema, graphql

I'm using Vesper which requires paths to .graphql files instead of importable schema. I also write in typescript so everything gets compiled into a build folder which means that I either have to drag all the .graphql files to the build folder manually after compiling, Or I have to reference the files from my src folder which works but just feels wrong.

Does anyone know a way or a tool to bundle all the .graphql files to a single schema.graphql file in the build folder during compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was by just specifying `./**/*.graphql` as the path.